# How to set Innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm having trouble changing the `innodb_log_file_size` variable. It seems mysql server is completely ignoring the configuration in `my-default.ini`. I suspect it is the case because when i wanted to increase the `max_allowed_packet` value, adding `max_allowed_packet=val` line to the file had no effect(that was when i had problems with `max_allowed_packet`, unluckily I can't set `innodb_log_file_size` through mysql commands).

I want to know how can I change the `innodb_log_file_size` in windows.

Things i've tried (and failed)

- `mysqld -u root -p --innodb_log_file_size=1745337664`
  gave the following error

> 2015-01-16 14:21:57 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT
>   value is   deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
>   server option (see  documentation for more details).

- `SET GLOBAL innodb_log_file_size=#`
  turned out to be a read only variable

I've copied the content of `my-default.ini` here. I'm having this issue with Mysql Server 5.6 and it's running on win 7 64-bit.

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=1G
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment: It doesn't use `my-default.ini`: it uses `my.ini`.

Comment: There's no my.ini in my installation directory(which is the default installation directory).

Comment: EJP, Your comment helped a bit. I renamed the file to my.ini and it worked. Thanks for motivating that thought.